# Multiple Images upload and show them as gallery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-file-upload

I need to upload multiple images in asp.net for a particular programme.
And I need to show them as Gallery Trainingwise. How can I achieve this.
Do I need to save images to database or saving in folder is enough. Im new to asp.net.Please Help me .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way to generic to get a complete answer. 
Saving images in folder or in database depends on what do you want to achieve. Here are some starting points:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667604/Upload-multiple-files-in-asp-net
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/multiple-image-upload-in-Asp-Net/

Please have a look and after that if you have questions please address them and include some code samples in your answer.